# Объединение множества массивов на js

Tags: javascript, html, css, массивы

Имеется несколько массивов вида:

```
arr1 = [1, 2];
arr2 = [3, 4, 5];
arr3 = [6, 7];
```

Количество массивов также как и количество значений в них может быть разным.
Необходимо объединять все массивы в один массив вида.

```
arr4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

Ума не приложу как это сделать.

Вообще задача заключается в том чтобы сделать редактируемую таблицу как в Excel. В данном случае нужно копировать некоторый кусок таблицы Excel например 5x6 и вставлять в мою таблицу на сайте. Всё работает, но только если копировать кусок 2x3 так как объединяю массивы я таким образом `arrRows = cells[0].concat(cells[1], cells[2]);`

**JS:**

```
$(this).on('paste', function(e) {

    var pasteData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');

    var rows = pasteData.split("\n");
    var arrRows = [];
    var cells = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
        cells[x] = rows[x].split("\t");
    }
    arrRows = cells[0].concat(cells[1], cells[2]);
    var best = [];
    best = $('.my-class');
    for (i = 0; i < arrRows.length; i++) {
        $(best[i]).html(arrRows[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arrs = [];
arrs[0] = [1, 2];
arrs[1] = [3, 4, 5];
arrs[2] = [6, 7];

let arrRows = [];
arrRows = arrRows.concat.apply(arrRows, arrs);

console.log(arrRows);
```

Comment: Всё идеально, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

[.concat() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2];
let arr2 = [3, 4, 5];
let arr3 = [6, 7];
console.log([].concat(arr1, arr2, arr3));
```

**upd:** Можно так:

```
arrRows = [].concat(...cells);
```

Comment: количество массивов может быть разным т.е. массивов может быть 2, 5 или даже 10

Comment: Ну как-то же нужно понять какие массивы объединять. Если это просто глобальные переменные, то по ним даже циклом не пройтись. Нужно, чтобы все эти массивы были частью чего-то одного - элементами другого массива или объекта, ну вы меня поняли.

Comment: внёс правки просмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Пример с деструктуризацией

Comment: Ваш пример тоже работает. Спасибо